# More efficient way to group data based on a mapping file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I can do this in excel but I am looking for a way to do this in python.   Do you know of a way to do the following

Initial

```
          District_1     District_2     District_3
Food      69             47             65
Water     87             86             32
Shelter   63             84             27
```

Mapping

```
District_1      London
District_2      London
District_3      Boston
```

Desired

```
          London          Boston
Food      116             65
Water     173             32
Shelter   147             27
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume your `mapping` is a dictionary

```
mapping = {'District_1': 'London', 'District_2': 'London', 'District_3': 'Boston'}
```

Then use `groupby` with `axis=1`

```
df.groupby(mapping, axis=1).sum()

         Boston  London
Food         65     116
Water        32     173
Shelter      27     147
```

When you pass a dictionary to `groupby`, its `get` method gets applied to the axis of choice (axis=0 by default) and the result defines the groups.

Comment: very elegant use of `groupby`

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderMcFarlane

Comment: I got this error @piRSquared TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Did you just try this now?  What version of Pandas are you using?