# Mapping multiple columns to a new column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like below and now I am trying to map multiple column values to new columns basically a many-to-one mapping.

dataframe:

```
 a   b   c    d    e    f    g    h
 0       2         6   -2   10     
     1   3                   4    7
     2  3.5  4.5   8   10.5       8.5
0.5          7.5        6.4       10
```

I created a dictionary showing which columns belong to the new column which looks like below.

If all the column has values in it, the new column should take the maximum value and if there are no values, the new column should have a NaN.

dictionary:

```
 {x : [a, c, d],
 {y : [b, e, g],
 {z : [f, h]}`
```

Expected Dataframe:

```
 a   b   c    d    e    f    g    h    x    y    z
 0       2          6   -2   10        2    10  -2
     1   3                   4    7    3    4    7
     2  3.5  4.5   8   10.5       8.5  4.5  8   10.5
0.5          7.5        6.4       10   7.5       10
```

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem and I would really appreciate if I can get some help with it.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52276757/2336654

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all values in lists are unique is possible change dictionary in dict comprehension, aggregate `max` and `join` together:

```
d =  {'x' : ['a', 'c', 'd'],'y' : ['b', 'e', 'g'], 'z' : ['f', 'h']}

#swap key values in dict
#http://stackoverflow.com/a/31674731/2901002
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}
#convert string repr of numbers to numeric columns
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce'))
df = df.join(df.groupby(d1, axis=1).max())
print (df)
     a    b    c    d    e     f     g    h    x     y     z
0  0.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  6.0  -2.0  10.0  NaN  2.0  10.0  -2.0
1  NaN  1.0  3.0  NaN  NaN   NaN   4.0  7.0  3.0   4.0   7.0
2  NaN  2.0  3.5  4.5  8.0  10.5   8.5  NaN  4.5   8.5  10.5
3  0.5  NaN  7.5  NaN  6.4   NaN  10.0  NaN  7.5  10.0   NaN
```

But if possible values in lists should be repeated (not unique per all lists):

```
d =  {'x' : ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],'y' : ['b', 'e', 'g', 'a'], 'z' : ['f', 'h']}
for k, v in d.items():
    df[k] = df.loc[:, v].max(axis=1) 
print (df)
     a    b    c    d    e     f     g    h     x     y     z
0  0.0  NaN  2.0  NaN  6.0  -2.0  10.0  NaN   6.0  10.0  -2.0
1  NaN  1.0  3.0  NaN  NaN   NaN   4.0  7.0   3.0   4.0   7.0
2  NaN  2.0  3.5  4.5  8.0  10.5   8.5  NaN  10.5   8.5  10.5
3  0.5  NaN  7.5  NaN  6.4   NaN  10.0  NaN   7.5  10.0   NaN
```

Comment: I believe the max function doesn't work if any of the columns have string values right.

Comment: @akash bachu use `df=df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x,errors='coerce'))`

Answer (score 3):

You can `groupby` `dict` , then `concat` back , before that we need adjust your `dict`

```
d={'x': ['a', 'c', 'd'],'y': ['b', 'e', 'g'],'z': ['f', 'h']}
from itertools import chain
d=dict(chain(*map(dict.items, [dict.fromkeys(y,x) for x,y in d.items()])))
df=pd.concat([df,df.groupby(d,axis=1).max()],axis=1)
```

Comment: @jezrael Man I usually can not watching the site in time like right now I am using my phone  sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: I believe the max function doesn't work if any of the columns have string values right.

Comment: @akashbachu yes, string does not work for max , you can adding `df=df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors=coerce,axis=1)` before above solution